# Shell interface in tmux does not work

Tags: bash, tmux, gnome-terminal

I using gnome-terminal and start in them tmux session. But in tmux all terminal feauters has not working.
Outside of tmux (in raw gnome-terminal) all working well.

History navigation does not work (`arrow up`/`arrow down` keys).
User name and current working directory does not show (e.g. `root@pc:/var/www$`). Only `$`
Autocompletion does not work (e.g `cd /var/ww<tab>`)
End etc...

How can I fix that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix usage, belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is your normal shell? `bash`?

Comment: all terminal features....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Stackoverflow does have a `tmux` tag, I would consider this question borderline.

It sounds like `tmux` is starting some shell other than your default shell.

Here is one possible fix for that, although whether it works may depend on what else is in your `.tmux.conf`.

Open `~/.tmux.conf` and put this line at the bottom.

```
set-option -g default-shell $SHELL
```